# An argument pattern that my function can treat as Times[constant, variable]

Tags: functions, argument-patterns

I want to define a function of two variables, `func[f_, g_]`, such that when it sees a general constant multiplying one of the variables, say `a`, it will take it outside the evaluated expression. So for example, if `f` and `g` are variables and `a` is a constant multiplying `g`, it will be evaluated as

```
func[f_, a_ g_]:= a func[f_, g_]
```

I need to inform *Mathematica* that `a` is a constant, not a variable, and that it should be pulled out of the expression.

Comment: m_goldberg, I know your edit was intended to be helpful, and the vast majority of your edits are, but I think it has been discussed that fixing syntax such as `func(a, b) = . . .` is a bad idea because the that is often a problem that needs to be addressed in the answers rather than "swept under the rug" as it were.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a clear differentiation of "constant" and "variable" and I don't see that in your question.  For the sake of the example let us consider anything numeric to be a constant and anything else to be a variable, so my [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) function will be [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumericQ.html).

```
func[f_, a_?NumericQ g_] := a func[f, g]
```

Now:

```
func[foo, 6 bar]

func[x, Pi y^2]
```

> ```
> 6 func[foo, bar]
>
> π func[x, y^2]
> ```

Comment: ok, but with this solution I want to insert a customized constant, say "a", and have the function pull it out. i.e. func[foo, a  bar] will yield a func[foo, bar]

Comment: @Gogo Do you have a list of expressions that you wish to consider constant?  Only literal `a`?  Something else?

Comment: Yes, I have a specific parameter. I want a factor "1/M" to be such a constant

Answer (score 1):

Assuming g is the only variable in the second position and any thing before is a constant:

```
ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless];
func[f_, a__ g_] := a func[f, g]

func[f, 3 g]
func[f, 3 Pi g]
func[f, 3 Pi a^3 g]
(*3 func[f, g]*)
(*3 \[Pi] func[f, g]*)
(*3 \[Pi] a^3 func[f, g]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a variation of Mr. Wizard's answer...

```
ClearAll[isConstantQ, func];
isConstantQ[v_] = False;
isConstantQ[1/M] = True;
SetAttributes[func, HoldRest];

func[f_, g : Times[a_, b_] /; isConstantQ[a]] := Times[a, func[f, b]];

func[f_, g_] := NormalFunc[f, g];

DownValues[func]
func[aa, 1/M bb]
func[aa, ZZ bb]
```

Results in

> ```
> {HoldPattern[func[f_, g : a_ b_ /; isConstantQ[a]]] :> a func[f, b], 
>  HoldPattern[func[f_, g_]] :> NormalFunc[f, g]}
> NormalFunc[aa, bb]/M
> NormalFunc[aa, bb ZZ]
> ```